# Disconnected Space Proof

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a topological space X is disconnected if and only if there exists a nonconstant continuous function from X to the discrete space {0,1}.

Proof: Since X is disconnected, we know that X can be represented as a union of two disjoint nonempty open subsets A, and B, hence X = A $\cup$ B. We want to find a nonconstant continuous function F from X to {0,1} where {0,1} is the discrete space. Define F(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x\in A$} \\ 1, & \text{if $x\in B$} \end{cases}.

F is continuous since for any $x \in X$ and F(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x\in A$} \\ 1, & \text{if $x\in B$} \end{cases}. The singletons {0} and {1} are both open and closed in Y, and the preimages $f^{-1}$(0) and $f^{-1}$(1) are also both open and closed in X. Thus F is continuous.

This is what I have thus far for my proof. I'm wondering if there needs to be any improvement. Problem is from John Lee's Topological Manifolds.

Comment: This seems correct to me. However, you have only proven the "only if" statement. You should also prove the "if" statement. Please, also check if $f^{-1}({0,1})$ and $f^{-1}(\empty)$ are open in X.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling that something was missing, I'll revise that part of the proof. I only reached the "only if" portion thus far but still going after the other end.

Answer (score 1):

The continuity of your $f$ is trivial to check and use here: a map into $\{0,1\}$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}[\{0\}$ is open and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is open. (The other open sets of $\{0,1\}$ are $\{0,1\}$ and $\emptyset$, which always have open pre-images).

So indeed a partition into opens defines a continuous map, and a continuous map defines a partition. The equivalence is a trivial reformulation in this light.

(As an aside:)
But it has served to define other notions of connectedness in categories. If $C$ is a non-empty, non-singleton object in a category (based on sets with structures), then $X$ is $C$-connected iff every morphism from $X$ to $C$ is constant. There is a notion of uniform connectedness in the category of uniform spaces, e.g. where the object $\{0,1\}$ is considered as a uniform space. e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ in its standard uniformity is uniformly connected, but not topologically connected, so we do get something different.